# Poor selection of duplicates by gold badge user

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This 'give me teh codez' question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603919/fetch-data-from-mysql) was asked yesterday. It's awful so I voted to close it as 'unclear' or 'too broad' (I forget which). A number of other users also voted, but the question was finally closed by a gold badge user as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761082/how-do-a-jfreechart-timeseriescollection-with-values-from-mysql-database).

Now, the original question is so poor it's difficult to tell what is being asked. It is tagged with jFreeChart, so I suppose there is some relevance, but it's also tagged with PHP and **not** Java, yet all the code in the supposed duplicate is in Java.

Whatever the original question is about, it's clear that the linked duplicate is, at best, a poor selection, and at worst, irrelevant.

This isn't the first time I have seen gold badge users choose a poor duplicate, so I'd like to know what the right course of action is, both in the general case, and in this particular instance.

Comment: If the post is going to be closed *anyway*, why not try and point to a possible duplicate?

Comment: While gold badger was involved, it still took 5 votes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In some cases that might be a good argument, but here the suggested duplicate is in Java, not PHP. We might assume that the PHP tag was an error, but equally we might conclude that the jFreechart tag is the mistake. My point is really that the selected duplicate really isn't a duplicate. My question remains: what should we do where that happens?

Comment: @plutonix Yes, but had the gold badge user shown up earlier the question would have been closed then, with fewer votes.

Comment: `what should we do where that happens?` Vote to reopen. But most importantly, place a comment with a correct duplicate link and an explanation that the duplicate was erroneous.

Comment: I don't see this as a real big problem (That maybe one question gets closed with a wrong dupe). If you compare how many question gets closed with a useful and "correct" dupe, then the "wrong" dupe count is just minimal. But I still think it should be cleared, by a comment (, maybe reopen vote and if you have the correct dupe, then it should be closed with that)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, if it is really a duplicate, great! If it isn't though, that just inhibited automatic cleanup and added a wrong signpost. Not so good, though not a catastrophe if rare enough. Not sure either way about the dupe.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Good suggestion. I'll bear it in mind for the future. For this case though, the question is so poor it probably shouldn't be reopened. Were it closed for some other reason it would simply fade away quite soon.

Comment: It should have been closed with the correct close reason, but it should have been deleted with _extreme_ prejudice well before it was reopened and closed.

Comment: @jeff Actually, I was hoping for exactly that in this case. I still have the question marked to return to in a couple of days when I can vote for  deletion. In the mean time it seems that the OP has returned to 'improve' his question. Spot the edit!

Comment: Well, it's been 20k deleted now, so this is sort of moot.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Voting such a question to *re-open* is contra-productive. (Keep in mind that the question itself is crap.) Basically the problem is, that the current search implementation on SO makes it sometimes super-hard to find the right dupe. You cannot expect from gold-badge user to go this annoying way every time a poor, and somewhat duplicate question arrives. Basically it counts that the question is closed. (Keep further in mind that the question is the problem - not the close vote)

Comment: I don't think the potential duplicate has to be in the same language as the OP's question.  Developers should be able to do a little investigative work to figure out how to translate (Java vs. C# vs VB.NET, for example, should be relatively simple).  The OP could also ask for a translation of what he is stumbling on if he has trouble.

Comment: @hek2mgl no. Then downvote, and close it as too broad, or unclear what you're asking, if applicable. Do not routinely apply bad duplicates, that's not what the dupe-hammer is there for and if people start doing that on a large scale, SE is going to take it away from us again. The fact that the OP was a lazy bastard and the question should be burninated is not an excuse to create a bad signpost for future generations

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure, you are basically right. Also I'm using the dupe-hammer really seldom - because it is often hard to find an appropriate duplicate even for obviously duplicate questions. This makes the feature less *hammer* for me. Improving the search functionality would be nice. However, sometimes I really appreciate if someone *simply closes it* to stop the madness below a poor question.

Comment: @hek I agree search facilities need to be optimized further, totally

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Vote to reopen and comment explaining your viewpoint. It's better to reopen a poor question than let it stay closed with an irrelevant duplicate link, otherwise it makes it look like we're just using duplicate closing privileges as a pretext to shut a question down arbitrarily. Your comment will be seen by people in the reopen queue and by other gold-badge users looking at the question, and somebody can act on it. When I'm in the reopen queue I look at the comments to see if anybody has a rationale either way, it helps a lot to leave an explaining comment.

When I close a question I'll add a comment sometimes to explain my rationale, part of why I do this is so anyone disagreeing can notify me in a comment. If the closing person has a comment on the post, notify them in your comment so they can be made aware. I try to be careful with my gold badge close vote power and I'm open to reconsidering close votes, if I made a bad decision I want to know so I can fix it.

Comment: This seems to be the best course of action. I certainly don't agree with the idea that we might as well find a duplicate if the question is to be closed anyway. My example is a particularly extreme example of a poor duplicate. I have seen others that were less clear cut so the 'reopen + comment' provides a good way of highlighting possible issues for any later visitor.

Comment: Seems like it might be tough to get a crappy question reopened, regardless of whether the current close reason makes sense or not. I wish there was a way to change a close reason without reopening the question.

Comment: @Ajedi32: yes, the other day i had a crappy question that was totally unclear and i voted to close. later the OP realized it was a duplicate but I couldn't close it as such since I'd already voted with the unclear reason.

Comment: I don't think this is good enough - if you feel that post worth reopening you need to make sure it looks ok - so edit post in shape. If you don't think editing could help -  I believe severely downvoted duplicates would be simply removed by roomba in a at most a month resulting in  the same net effect - post gone from the site.

Answer (score 9):

My suggestion would be to post a comment saying:

1. It's not a duplicate
2. Why it's not a duplicate
3. That it should remain closed
4. Why it should remain closed
5. What can be done to fix it, or giving additional context
6. Perhaps pointing out something specific to the question that should be fixed
7. Linking to the help center.

Example:

> This question is not a duplicate because this question is about ..., while the duplicate is about ..., but it should remain closed because it's unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. See [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

---

I would say we should **not** be reopening these questions. Closing and reopening a question takes some effort from quite a few people (especially when we're talking about duplicates, even more so when it's not 100% obvious that it's not a duplicate), and draws quite a bit of attention to the question. Given that these question are not appropriate for the site, this effort and attention is really just wasting everyone's time, and perhaps re-enforcing the belief that such questions are appropriate.

---

An argument can be made for flagging it for moderator attention, but moderators don't necessarily have the domain knowledge to be able to tell whether questions are duplicates.