# Incorrect choice of duplicate by gold badge user

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

A while back I wrote an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928929/jquery-ajax-call-executes-error-on-200/20929815) question. I recently checked back on it and noticed that it had been closed as a duplicate of [Ajax request returns 200 OK, but an error event is fired instead of success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success). Viewing that question I was surprised that it could be deemed a duplicate given the differences between the two in terms of both questions and answers.

I asked the closer for some clarification on why it got the dupehammer and his responses left me with the impression that the question was closed for reasons that did not add up.

What course of action should be taken here? Could we get this one reopened or at least closed with a better choice of duplicate?

Comment: Related : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300163/poor-selection-of-duplicates-by-gold-badge-user?cb=1

Answer (score -2):

This question already had an answer. That's the reason why. Does it not seem like a fair reason to close a question? We don't need duplicate answers.

Comment: My point is that the questions and answers are different to the extent that the two are not duplicates. If they were very similar then yes, closing as a duplicate is of course the right way to go. My concern is that the someone searching for a similar question to the closed one will not find the answer in the other.

Comment: The only question OP posted was "Is this a bug in jquery?" which would make it seem like a good reason to mark it as a duplicate. On top of that your answer of setting   HttpStatusCode.NoContent would also make it seem like it's a duplicate answer to me.

Comment: But a duplicate of what, exactly? The chosen duplicate is really quite different. What's more, it is not a bug in jQuery, the OP was simply sending the wrong status code - that was the real question I was answering.

Comment: @nick_w The dupe is right. Sorry, but that's the facts.

Comment: @Deduplicator Care to explain how?